# Should I ask programming questions without code samples on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, questions, code

If I ask any question without sample code, some members are saying this question shouldn't be on Stack Overflow; ask somewhere else. Is it not allowed to ask such question?

I would like to hear some feasible method proposal for it, but I am not able to post since a member saying things like that.

Is it?

Comment: It obviously depends. When you ask "Why doesn't my code work" without showing that code, yes that is off-topic. If you ask something that doesn't need code, then it doesn't need it. Do you have an example?

Comment: Asking you for code might also be a symptom of posting a specification and asking how to achieve that. StackOverflow is not a coding service and questions have to be answerable in just a few paragraphs. People might ask you in such questions for your code because they want to see what you already have and to limit the scope of your problem.

Comment: If you post a question that doesn't belong on [so], we are of course not responsible for finding you a place where you are allowed to ask things. If you suspect there is another site in the [se] infrastructure, feel free to ask on their meta site if you question is appropriate (you have enough rep to be able to do that), but in general **you** are responsible for finding sites that can help you, if your questions are not appropriate for [so], not we. That is even if someone here might know where to point you.